# calculate duration for the given set of timestamp

Tags: time, php

I have a set of intime and outtime, and i want to calculate the duration between the intime and outtime and add all the duration to get the total duration.
example:

```
Array
    (
    [1] => Array
        (
            ['intime'] => 1342086993
            ['outime'] => 1342087585
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            ['intime'] => 1342087669
            ['outtime] => 1342096165
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            ['intime'] => 1342096339
            ['outime'] => 1342096345
        )
    )

$total_duration = 0;
foreach($logArray as $log)
{
  $duration = $log['outime'] - $log['intime'];
  $total_duration += $duration;
}

$duration_hrs = $total_duration/3600;
echo 'Time spend in hrs :'.$duration_hrs;
```

but this is not giving me the proper duration. is there any other way to do so.

Comment: Are those `'` before `Array` and after `)` there on purpose? Seems to me like syntax error... and many more like that ...

Comment: @DainisAbols that was a mistake while copy-pasting the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax free script, works for me fine:

```
<?php

    $logArray = Array (
        1 => Array (
            'intime' => 1342086993,
            'outime' => 1342087585
        ),
        3 => Array (
            'intime' => 1342087669,
            'outime' => 1342096165
        ),
        5 => Array (
            'intime' => 1342096339,
            'outime' => 1342096345
        )
    );

    $total_duration = 0;
    foreach( $logArray as $log ) {
      $duration = $log[ 'outime' ] - $log[ 'intime' ];
      $total_duration += $duration;
        echo $duration / 3600 . "<br />";
    }

    $duration_hrs = $total_duration / 3600;
    echo 'Time spend in hrs: ' . $duration_hrs;

?>
```

And the output:

```
0.16444444444444
2.36
0.0016666666666667
Time spend in hrs: 2.5261111111111
```

Seems like your time format is not right: `13, July 2012 04:04:32 PM` should be `13. July 2012 04:04:32 PM` for

```
strtotime('13. July 2012 04:04:32 PM')
```

to work right. It should give `1342195472` instead of you `1342168834`. So check your time formats that are generating wrong microtimes

Comment: check this array, Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1342168834
            [1] => 1342175672
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1342179242
            [1] => 1342179244
        )

) its giving me 1.9 these are timestamp for [13, July 2012 02:10:34 PM(intime)],[13, July 2012 04:04:32 PM (outtime)] and [13, July 2012 05:04:02 PM (intime)], [13, July 2012 05:04:04 PM (outtime)]

Comment: Witch array? Anyways, why don't you post the results you get, meaning, the whole output.

Comment: Well, seems like your time format is not right: `13, July 2012 04:04:32 PM` should be `13. July 2012 04:04:32 PM` for strtotime('13. July 2012 04:04:32 PM') to work right. + it gives `1342195472` instead of you `1342168834`. So check your time formats that are generating wrong microtimes.

Answer (score 2):

Use [array_map](http://php.net/array_map) to first map each element to the duration, and then [array_sum](http://php.net/array_sum) to sum them:

```
$durations = array_map(function ($e) {
  return $e['outtime'] - $e['intime'];
}, $logArray);
$total_duration = array_sum($durations);
```

Comment: It works for me, yes. I tried with the values `10->15, 25->35, 100->150` and correctly got `65` (in seconds).

Answer (score 0):

```
$total_duration = 0;
foreach($logArray as $log)
{
  $duraton = $log['outtime'] - $log['intime'];
  $total_duration += $duration;
}
$duration_hrs = $total_duration/3600;
echo 'Time spend in hrs :'.$duration_hrs;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a simple typo in your code. check that:

```
duraton vs duration
```

change and will be fine.

Comment: :) just a copy paste mistake...in code it would throw me an error..but thats not the case..

Comment: from code I can see that you are subtracting things wrong. subtract $out - $in to get difference in interval.